# Giving an array of indexes, how to push items from one array to another depending on the indexes that are specified?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to push items from one Array to another depending on the order that is supplied. Essentially i have a 2d array with a name and a price :

```
var myArray = [['Apples',22],['Orange',55],['Berry',23]];
```

Another array with the order it should be in :

```
var myOrder = [0,2,1];
```

My resulting array would look like this :

```
var finalArray = [['Apples',22],['Berry',23],['Orange',55]]
```

My initial thought process was to loop through myArray and loop through myOrder , store the object temporary at a specified index in myOrder then push to final array. I think i am over thinking it a bit, i made several attempts but with no luck whatsoever. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a simple `map()` that doesn't require anything else

```js
var myArray = [['Apples',22],['Orange',55],['Berry',23]];
var myOrder = [0,2,1];

let final = myOrder.map(i =>  myArray[i])

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 2):

The optimal way appears to me to be:

1. Initialize empty `finalArray`
2. Loop over your `myOrder` array

   2.1. Push `myArray[index]` to `finalArray`

Like so:

```
let finalArray = [];
for(let index of myOrder) {
    finalArray.push(myArray[index]);
}
```

Review the [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) syntax if you're not familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `splice` to insert so long as the same number of elements are present in both the arrays.

You iterate over the `myOrder` array and then use splice, to which the `index` of the new array is the current value of the iteration and then use array present in the index position of `myArray`

```js
var myArray = [['Apples',22],['Orange',55],['Berry',23]];
var myOrder = [0,2,1];

var finalArray = [];

myOrder.forEach(function(val, index) {
    finalArray.splice(val, 0, myArray[index]);
});

console.log(finalArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough using `.reduce`:

```js
var myArray = [['Apples',22],['Orange',55],['Berry',23]];
var myOrder = [0,2,1];

function reorder(array, order) {
    return order.reduce((newArray, orderIndex) => {
        newArray.push(array[orderIndex]);
        return newArray;
    }, []);
}

console.log(reorder(myArray, myOrder))
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution works perfectly, what would be the best solution to use as another commenter had a different approach and works perfectly as well?

Comment: @GrandeurH If they both work I'd say its up to you to decide. Perhaps you find one more readable than the other, or one might be more performant (although I don't know which).

Comment: I find the other easier for myself to understand so i will go for that one but i do appreciate your answer as well

Answer (score 1):

```
function reorder(arr, order) {
  return order.map(function(i) {
    return arr[i];
  });
}

var myArray = [['Apples',22],['Orange',55],['Berry',23]];
var myOrder = [0,2,1];
reorder(myArray, myOrder); // => [["Apples",22],["Berry",23],["Orange",55]]
```

Answer (score 1):

One of way solving this will be

```
var myArray = [['Apples',22],['Orange',55],['Berry',23]];
var myOrder = [0,2,1];
var finalArray;
for (x in myOrder) {
    finalArray[x] = myArray[myOrder[x]];
}
```

This is a beginning level solution. Also you use libraries available for java script such as underscore.js(http://underscorejs.org/) for such operations on Array and Object.

Also you can use ECMA 6, for doing this which will reduce your line of coding.
Example-

```
var myArray = [['Apples',22],['Orange',55],['Berry',23]];
var myOrder = [0,2,1];
let finalArray = myOrder.map(i =>  myArray[i])
```

This is the new way of coding in javascript.
In my point of view, it will be easy if you learn latest version of Java script(ECMAscript 6)